# Permission denied during pytest --cov execution on docker in travis-ci

Tags: python, docker, travis-ci, coveralls

I have a problem during execution pytest command on docker on travisci side. After performing command:

```
docker exec my_package pytest --cov=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my_package tests/ -vvv
```

Following error is visible:

```
tests/test_views/test_users.py::test_get_users PASSED                    [100%]
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 209, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 249, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 68, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 62, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     gen.send(outcome)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 229, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     self.cov_controller.finish()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_cov/engine.py", line 167, in finish
INTERNALERROR>     self.cov.stop()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coverage/control.py", line 782, in save
INTERNALERROR>     self.data_files.write(self.data, suffix=self.data_suffix)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coverage/data.py", line 680, in write
INTERNALERROR>     data.write_file(filename)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coverage/data.py", line 467, in write_file
INTERNALERROR>     with open(filename, 'w') as fdata:
INTERNALERROR> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/.coverage'
```

This issue is permanent on travisci. But it's strange that the same commands work on local docker container. I can't use root user in Dockerfile cause few of my tests required non-authorized user.

.travis.yml

```
---
dist: xenial
services:
  - docker
language: python
python:
  - "3.7"
script:
  - docker-compose up --build -d
  - docker exec  my_package_container pytest --cov=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my_package tests/ -vvv
  - docker exec my_package_container coveralls
  - docker-compose down
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /code

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y musl-dev gcc postgresql

ADD requirements-test.txt /code/
RUN pip3 -r requirements-test.txt

COPY . /code
RUN pip3 install .

EXPOSE 5000

RUN useradd user
USER user
```

Comment: Have you tried running the `RUN useradd user; USER user` after the `RUN apt-get`? Since you run the `COPY` as root, it's likely that the code coverage result can't write to the folder created by root, causing the issue